# How to find job seekers in a big conference? (Like the AMS-MAA Joint Meetings)

Tags: mathematics, conference, networking, recruiting

I am heading to the AMS/MAA Joint Meetings in Boston soon. My mathematics department in Xiamen University (Malaysia) has a couple of open permanent positions this cycle, and I would like to meet job seekers at the Joint Meetings and ask them to consider applying. We have had some success recruiting American postdocs in the past through online advertising on the AMS's Mathjobs website.

This conference attracts a lot of job seekers because many American universities hold interviews during the conference. So what is the best way for me to meet and get the word out to job seekers at the conference?

Comment: Many conferences have a recruiting center set up for just this purpose. For you, see https://www.ams.org/profession/employment-services/employment-center/employment-center?_ga=2.175695266.1005756068.1672586784-983556044.1672586784

Comment: By "job seekers" do you mean people who are looking for a faculty job in general, or people who have already submitted an application to your position?

Comment: @NateEldredge I mean people looking for a faculty job in general

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Announce it at the end of your talk. Most potential candidates would listen to your talk because it is similar to what they are doing and that is what, I think, you need. (*As Moishe Kohan pointed out in the comment, this might not be suitable for AMS-MAA meetings but it is common in other events/disciplines*)
2. Distribute flyers.
3. Use coffee breaks to communicate with people you think would be an asset to your department.
4. Send (semi) personal messages/emails to potential candidates after, for example, listening to their talks. You can easily find people by googling their names.
5. Use the recruiting centre.

Comment: Did you ever attend an AMS/MAA Joint Meeting? Just AMS has about 130 special sessions...

Comment: @MoisheKohan no, but what makes it special?

Comment: That what I thought. "Special" is just a word used by AMS, it means that there is a particular main topic, say, "symplectic geometry," of the talks at the session. Now, think of your advice #1: OP is not trying to recruit in their particular area, say, symplectic geometry. Such an advertisement will reach out to, 25 people or so.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I added a note to #1. However, I think that's the point: to reach less but to hit the target (systematic search). I don't see the point of reaching 100+ but only 1 is adequate for the position. Also, when giving a talk is also about advertising oneself as an attractive colleague or supervisor.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yeah, but it still helps  because people in a talk can think "Ah, hmm, Moishe is looking for a job, I should tell him to check out Darren."

Answer (score 4):

It is almost certainly too late to implement the following for this year, but for future reference...

Many such large conferences have an exhibits area where various organizations (book sellers, etc) set up booths. There is a fee for this, of course. You could in future set up a booth advertising your university and its faculty needs. Staff it with people who can be helpful to a prospective hire. That could include students, actually.

Then, you could rent a hotel room at the venue and contract with the hotel to set up a buffet in that room on one of the nights during the conference. Use the exhibits area to hand out invitations to the buffet to anyone who seems promising and use the buffet room itself to have conversations with people. The invitation should indicate that the buffet is for recruiting, so people come prepared.

This might be costly and requires advanced planning. Some companies do this at some conferences in CS, for example, as part of recruiting.

---

This page shows some options: https://www.jointmathematicsmeetings.org//jmm